# How to add characters to input form when clicked with button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Am trying to use button, that if the button is onclick it would add special characters, but when I did it, if I click it, it shows, but if I click another button with another characters or numbers or tests, that one which was there will be replacing itself, but not like that in numbers and letters but only at special characters that's with JavaScript o, am trying to make the special characters like "*" I want it plenty as I clicked on the button but it will appear there but it can't be plenty, please can anyone help me with it?

This is the HTML code

```
<input type="text" class="article" name="num" id="num" value="0" autocomplete="off" disabled=""/>

<div class="divd" id="k" onclick="a()">&times;</div>
```

This the JavaScript code

```
let num = document.getElementById("num");

function a() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10);
  value += "*";
  document.getElementById('num').value = value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your explanation doesn't make much sense to me and your code is compressed. Can you [edit] the post to share readable code with complete HTML (e.g. `#num`), please?

Comment: well parseInt is going to remove strings and just return the number

Comment: Have explained more better

Comment: You have `onclick="k()"` and `function a() {...`. Are they supposed to be the same function? Or do you have a `k` function and an `a` function?

Comment: Are you trying to make a way for users to build a string by clicking buttons that represent various characters? For example, `10 * 3 + 7`. In which case you'd have a button that represents `*` and another button that represents `+`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles That's the poin I want to go to. Like if they click button which input * into the text input field and it appears there, if I then click it again, another one won't appear and if I click another button like which have +, that's * is going to change to + which suppose not to be like that. And the buttons with numbers are not doing like that. And I can click as many times I wish in the buttons of numbers. And I knew the problem is those characters I put there that course the problem, so I need help

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` here: `var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10);` ? Because, as mentioned previously in comments, `parseInt` strips all non numeric characters. Does `var value = document.getElementById('num').value;` work for you? It does for me.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Please am having problem in my code, am creating a calculator, and everything now are working fine, but how to get the input value answer that's what I did did not work, is just bringing out the way it is out, eg, 2+2 the value it brought out was that same 2+2 and I need it to solve it, please is there anyway, maybe you should try and send me the code like the one up this my code

Comment: <input type="text" class="article" name="num" id="num" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled=""/>.                       
               <div type="submit" class="dive" id="btn" onclick="btn()">=</div>

function btn() {
   let num = document.getElementById("num");
   let x = document.getElementById("num").value;
   alert(x);
}